# iOS/Objective-C UILabel text kerning

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, interface-builder, uilabel

I was searching how to increase character spacing in `UILabel`s to make my UI Design implementations more attractive. I found following [answer, which tells it allows to adjust the **Text Kerning**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34248207/1752988), and it's written in *Swift*.

But what I needed is an Objective-C Solution. So I tried to convert the following code snippet:

```swift
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class KerningLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var kerning:CGFloat = 0.0{
        didSet{
            if ((self.attributedText?.length) != nil)
            {
                let attribString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.attributedText!)
                attribString.addAttributes([NSKernAttributeName:kerning], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.attributedText!.length))
                self.attributedText = attribString
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to following in Objective-C:

**KerningLabel.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface KerningLabel : UILabel
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat kerning;
@end
```

**KerningLabel.m:**

```
#import "KerningLabel.h"

@implementation KerningLabel
@synthesize kerning;
- (void) setAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)attributedText {
    if ([self.attributedText length] > 0) {
        NSMutableAttributedString *muAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
        [muAttrString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@(self.kerning) range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.attributedText length])];
        self.attributedText = muAttrString;
    }
}
@end
```

And it gives the following Attribute in XCode IB to adjust the kerning:

[image]

But it really doesn't seem to be taking effect on the UI when the App is running and also in the Interface Builder the text disappears.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update your `attributedText` every time kerning is updated. So, your .h should look like:

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface KerningLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat kerning;

@end
```

and your .m :

```
@implementation KerningLabel

- (void)setKerning:(CGFloat)kerning
{
    _kerning = kerning;

    if(self.attributedText)
    {
        NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
        [attribString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@(kerning) range:NSMakeRange(0, self.attributedText.length)];
        self.attributedText = attribString;
     }
}

@end
```

Comment: Perfect! It has resolved the mistakes I've made in the above code in the question. Now it lets me to edit kerning in the IB.